# Linter not working correctly: Atom

Tags: package, atom-editor, lint, eslint

I installed [atom](https://atom.io/), and I am trying to add a eslinter. I added [linter](https://atom.io/packages/linter) and [linter-eslint](https://atom.io/packages/linter-eslint). It worked fine until I added the [atom-beautify](https://atom.io/packages/atom-beautify) package.

The linters does their jobs, but when I 'beautify' the JavaScript code, most errors in the code panel don't show, but they do show at the bottom. Here's what I mean:

**Before beautify the code:**

[image]

[image]

**After Beautify the code:**
[image]
[image]

How can I get the errors to show even after I beautify the code?

Here's a list of all Community Packages:

- [atom-beautify](https://atom.io/packages/atom-beautify)
- [autoclose-html](https://atom.io/packages/autoclose-html)
- [file-icons](https://atom.io/packages/file-icons)
- [highlight-selected](https://atom.io/packages/highlight-selected)
- [linter](https://atom.io/packages/linter)
- [linter-eslint](https://atom.io/packages/linter-eslint)
- [minimap](https://atom.io/packages/minimap)
- [minimap-highlight-selected](https://atom.io/packages/minimap-highlight-selected)
- [open-recent](https://atom.io/packages/open-recent)

Comment: Hi @Jessica: could you show more info about your environment? Which version of node, Atom and eslint package you are using?

Comment: I'm using the latest versions of them all

Comment: okay, thank you. I will keep an eye on your case. Until now it did not happen for me yet.

Do you use the config files from our repository? 

https://github.com/GreenGlobalDevs/node-style-guide

Comment: No. I don't. I'm not sure what that is.

Comment: @Jessica, I am running into the same problem. Did you find a fix?

Comment: @ElliotHimmelfarb no. I wasn't able to fix it. I just switched to sublime text. Let me know if your'e able to fix it.

Comment: verified for: $ atom --version
Atom    : 1.13.0
Electron: 1.3.13
Chrome  : 52.0.2743.82
Node    : 6.5.0
I suspect it's a bug in atom-beautify.

Comment: same problem here, very annoying bug...